# How to calculate the data rate of IEEE 802.15.4 to be 250kbps?

Tags: frequency-spectrum, bandwidth

How to calculate the data rate of IEEE 802.15.4 to be 250 kbps

Comment: Could you rephrase a little the title from the content ?

Comment: The standard says that at 2.4 GHz band the over the air data rate of the channel is 250 kbps, but i am looking for its justification as if how this value is calculated?

Comment: Could you include that (and other info you have) in your question ?

Comment: 4 bits per symbol and 62.5 kbaud, the link might help it contains all the details of the standard [link (http://ecee.colorado.edu/~liue/teaching/comm_standards/2015S_zigbee/802.15.4-2011.pdf)

Comment: The rate is not really calculated, it is specified.

Comment: yes its specified that's why i asked the question how this value is calculated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have $16$-ary symbols, each symbol requires $4$ bits. With a chip rate of $1000$ K, the symbol rate is $1000/16=62.5$ K, hence the bit rate is $4\times 62.5=250$ Kbps. Did you mean this calculation?

Comment: Thanks @msm, can you please provide a reference for the formula you are using, I mean what is the exact formula of symbol rate by which you calculated the 62.5 kbaud, although as per wikipedia symbol rate, baud rate and modulation rate are same things. please explain the relationship between chip rate and symbol rate. thanks

Comment: I used no specific formula, but I can explain it to you more (maybe you can write it down as a formula). So we use a modulation with strings of length 16 to represent each symbol. Hence, we divide chip rate to symbol length to find the symbol rate first. Next, the bits per symbol is 4 (since 4 bits can represent a symbol). So bit rate is (symbol rate)(bits per symbol), and symbol rate is (chip rate/length of symbol).